# Angularjs validation issue for password field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-forms

Here is my `angularjs` code for the password field :

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="signup.registerPassword"  ng-minlength="8" >
<small class="errorMessage" data-ng-show="signupForm.registerPassword.$dirty && signupForm.registerPassword.$error.minlength"> Minimum 8 characters.</small>
<small class="errorMessage" data-ng-show="signupForm.registerPassword.$dirty && signupForm.registerPassword.$error.required"> Enter password again.</small>
```

when I type the password below 8 character it is not showing any error.

what is the mistake I am doing and how can I fix it ?

Comment: The above password rule is not working, i.e., it is not showing error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`registerPassword` is `ng-model` value. `signupForm` will have its field inside it by there name attribute. As you are gave `name="password"` to your field having `password` field in it not form, Then internally angular places the `password` field inside  `signupForm` scope variable.

Change `signupForm.registerPassword` to `signupForm.password`

**Markup**

```
<small class="errorMessage" data-ng-show="signupForm.password.$dirty && signupForm.password.$error.minlength"> Minimum 8 characters.</small>
<small class="errorMessage" data-ng-show="signupForm.password.$dirty && signupForm.password.$error.required"> Enter password again.</small>
```